# Python's math module & "Think Python"

Tags: python, function, module

I'm stucked on the chapter 3.3 "Math functions" of "Think Python".

It tells me to import math (through the interpreter).
Then print math and that I should get something like this:
`<module 'math' from '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/math.so'>`

Instead I get `<module 'math' <built-in>>`

Anyway that's not the problem. Though I wasn't able to find a 'math.so' file in my python folder. The most similar file is named test_math.

The problem is that I'm supposed to write this:
`>>> ratio = signal_power / noise_power`

`>>> decibels = 10 * math.log10(ratio)`

`>>> radians = 0.7`

`>>> height = math.sin(radians)`

When I write the first line it tells me this:
`Traceback <most recent call last>:`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`NameError: name 'signal_power' is not defined`

On the book says "The first example uses log10 to compute a signal-to-noise ratio in decibels (assuming that signal_power and noise_power are defined)."

So I assume that the problem might be that I didn't defined 'signal_power', but I don't know how to do it and what to assign to it...

This is the first time that I feel that this book is not holding my hand and I'm already lost. To be honest I don't understand this whole chapter.

By the way, I'm using Python2.7 and Windows XP. I may copy and paste the whole chapter if anyone feels that I should do it.
Python is my first language and I already tried to learn it using "Learn Python the hard way" but got stucked on chapter 16. So I decided to use "Think Python" and then go back to "Learn Python the hard way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to assign a value to both `signal_power` and `noise_power`. The author likely left them out because the values are arbitrary. Even when supplied with exact values in a text, you should also play around with the values. After all, there's not much point in having you type anything in if the results on the screen are the same as on the page.

```
signal_power = 100
noise_power = 17
```

This particular example defines the mathematical relationship between variables. If it were presented as such, it wouldn't be such a mystery that exact values were left out, as they would be supplied by someone when using the formula. The same holds for the code sample.

Comment: Thank you and the others for your help. Now I get it. It was pretty obvious but I couldn't see it...                                     I followed the steps and could get the result, but I still can't get the chapter itself. I think that it's my lack of math knowledge. I'm going to do some research about the terms that appeared (such as radians) and may come back to ask something here (can I ask another question here or should I begin another topic?)                                              Also, should I start studying some math to make this programming learning easier?

Comment: For all but research level math questions, there's [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/), though the basic ones (such as radians vs degrees) are already covered on other sites; start with [mathforum.org](http://mathforum.org), especially by searching the [Ask Dr Math](http://mathforum.org/dr.math/) archives.

Comment: The main gain of studying math is the mental discipline, rather than what you learn about any particular topic; you learn how to think rigorously. As for asking multiple questions, SO uses a Q&A, rather than forum, format. Each question should be distinct, and shouldn't involve discussion. Read the FAQ for more.

Answer (score 3):

You've figured it out - you have to set `signal_power`'s value before using it. As to what you have to set it to - it's not really a Python related question, but `1` is always a safe choice :) While you are at it, don't forget to define `noise_power`.

Answer (score 1):

The book is for an older version of python apparently. But that is unrelated to your actual question.

Try defining `signal_power`. For example

```
signal_power = 0
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea to set it to `0` because later on a `log10` of it is computed and `log10(0)` is -infinity which is not particularly useful for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable without defining/declaring it first. When you say `ratio = signal_power / noise_power`,
you're trying to access two variables that the interpreter has never heard about.

Before telling the machine what to do with the variables, you have to introduce them to it first.

You do this by declaring them:

```
signal_power = 123
noise_power = 321
```

You can define them as any number you want, not only 123 and 321, but you must define them before using them.